# How to get multiple image from the server in ionic app?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4

I want to get multiple images from the server in my app. So for this, I try this code:

```
<div class="one-image" *ngFor="let image of [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20]">
  <img src="http://mysite.co.in/ionic/{{image}}.jpg">
</div>
```

Here I have a working code, this way everything working fine but if I have more then 100 images in a folder at that time what to do? every time write image number is not good or is there any way to get all image from a folder in app...please help :)

Comment: will you name the image only as number?

Comment: yes, actually I added like this 1.jpg,2.jpg,3.jpg.....etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve them by looping the number of images. Assign the images count from the server and loop them like this

In ts file

```
imgRange = 100;
imgArr = [];
for(let i=1; i<=imgRange; i++){
this.imgArr.push(i);
}
```

Then in html

```
<div class="one-image" *ngFor="let image of imgArr">
  <img src="http://mysite.co.in/ionic/{{image}}.jpg">
</div>
```

Comment: please explain little more...where or how can I put the code in ts file?

Comment: Put this in your component where you are loading the images

Comment: i have forgot to add let in the loop check now